# Every Finite Group is a torsion group?

Tags: finite-groups, torsion-groups

I am learning about finitely generated groups at the moment and in the text book, they mention torsion groups, which they give the definition as:

> A group $G$ is a torsion group if every element of $G$ is of finite order.

They then go on to state, when listing examples of torsion groups, that

> "Every finite group is a torsion group"

I understand how cyclic groups would be a torsion group, but I am having trouble understand how a finite permutation group would be a torsion group. If anyone could help clarify why, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Every permutation of a finite set has finite order. If a group is finite the sequence of powers of any element must repeat, so the element has finite order.

Comment: Suppose $x \in G$ has not finite order: then the subgroup generated by $x$ is infinite. This shows that $G$ has infinitely many elements. Hence, if you consider a finite group $G$. necessarily all of its elements have finite order.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, it makes sense now.

Answer (score 1):

The order of an element $g$ is the cardinality of $\langle g \rangle$, the cyclic group generated by it.

Every element $g$ in a finite group $G$ has finite order because $\langle g \rangle \subseteq G$ implies that $\langle g \rangle $ is finite.